# BeautifulSoup4 not finding div

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been experimenting with BeautifulSoup4 lately and have found pretty good success across a range of different sites. Though I have stumbled into an issue when trying to scrape amazon.com.

Using the code below, when printing 'soup' I can see the div, but when I search for the div itself, BS4 brings back null. I think the issue is in how the html is being processed. I've tried with LXML and html5lib. Any ideas?

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_fcr_s-4_a870_dls_UPCM?gb_f_deals1=dealStates:AVAILABLE%252CWAITLIST%252CWAITLISTFULL,includedAccessTypes:GIVEAWAY_DEAL,sortOrder:BY_SCORE,enforcedCategories:2619533011,dealTypes:LIGHTNING_DEAL&pf_rd_p=56200e05-4eb2-42ca-9723-af0811ada870&pf_rd_s=slot-4&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=PQNZWZRKVD93HXXVG5A7&ie=UTF8'

original = http.request('Get',url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(original.data, 'lxml')

div = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'a-row padCenterContainer'})
```

Comment: this div is inside a script, for that reason soup can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to allow the javascript to load before grabbing the html.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_fcr_s-4_a870_dls_UPCM?gb_f_deals1=dealStates:AVAILABLE%252CWAITLIST%252CWAITLISTFULL,includedAccessTypes:GIVEAWAY_DEAL,sortOrder:BY_SCORE,enforcedCategories:2619533011,dealTypes:LIGHTNING_DEAL&pf_rd_p=56200e05-4eb2-42ca-9723-af0811ada870&pf_rd_s=slot-4&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=PQNZWZRKVD93HXXVG5A7&ie=UTF8'
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'a-row padCenterContainer'})
print(div.prettify())
```

The output of this script was too long to put in this question but [here is a link to it](https://bpaste.net/show/51354b7f4b62)